# Cannot save to network drive using MS Office 2010 over SMB

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010, hotfix

I have recently installed MS Office 2010 on a Windows 7 laptop. Everything works except for saving onto the network drive using MS Office 2010 applications (Word, Excel, etc)

Every time I try to save using one of these applications on the network I get the error :

> Document cannot be saved due to network permissions or the drive has
>   been disconnected.

However I can save to the network drive with other applications including Adobe Photoshop, I just can't save using MS Office.

I found the issue on the [Microsoft Support KB Article 983458](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983458) however the hotfix does not apply to my computer when I try to install.

As a work around I am saving files locally and dragging then to the network folder but this is getting a but annoying now. Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to apply the hotfix? Which version did you download for your computer? According to the linked forum, you need version `6.1.7600.20706` for `x86/x64`. Or fix `Fix321330`.

Comment: I found this an unhelpful soution but it worked by using the UNC path https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/291156

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have FULL control on the share and it's underlying file folder.

If you've had your Delete permission removed/denied (yet still have write permission) then you can run into this with Office 2010 due to it not being able to delete the temporary file it makes while you're editing, and if it can't delete it during the save routine, the Save fails..

Perhaps also check out this related SU question: [Avoid Powerpoint(/Word) 2010 creating temporary files in working directory](https://superuser.com/questions/309057/avoid-powerpoint-word-2010-creating-temporary-files-in-working-directory)